# Comprimir imagenes con imagemagick para php

Tags: php

Hola comunidad buenas tardes alguien por aqui a usado la libreria de imagemagick con php para comprimir imagenes ya que estoy usando una funcion pero no velo los cambios cuando reviso el peso de las imagen, ese código es el que hay en un ejemplo de la documentación.

```
namespace Compacted_Imagick;

class Compacted_Imagick {

/*
 * Configuracion inicial
 */

public  $setting = [
    'degrees' => 360,
    'length' => 16,
    'startlength' => 97,
    'lastlength' => 122,
    'patronspaces' => '/\W/'
];


public function compresed($file,$output,$quality) {
    $img = new \Imagick($file);
    $imgmagick = new \Imagick();

    $imgmagick->setcompressionquality($quality);
    $imgmagick->newpseudoimage(
            $img->getimagewidth(),
            $img->getimageheight(), 'canvas:white');
    $imgmagick->setformat('jpg');

    return $output = $img->getimageblob();
  }
}
```

aquí coloco un ejemplo de como uso esta función

```
public function processImage() {
    require_once (ROOT.DS.'vendor'.DS.'imagickcompacted'.DS.'Compacted_Imagick.php');
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $imgtmp = $this->request->data['name_imagen'];
        if($imgtmp['name'] != NULL){
           //esta es mi clase que contiene la funcion
            $img = new \Compacted_Imagick\Compacted_Imagick();
            $dir = new Folder();
            $dir->create(ROOT.DS.'tmpupload'.DS.$this->Auth->user('person_id'),TRUE, 0755);
            $mv = new File($imgtmp['tmp_name']);
            $mv->copy(ROOT.DS.'tmpupload'.DS.$this->Auth->user('person_id').DS.$imgtmp['name']);
            $path = ROOT.DS.'tmpupload'.DS.$this->Auth->user('person_id').DS.$imgtmp['name'];
            //Aqui obtengo la extensión para crear el nuevo archivo 
            $ext = pathinfo($imgtmp['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           //aqui el nuevo nombre de la imagen
            $name_image_2 = $img->uniquename();
            //luego la ruta donde se copiara la imagen
            $path_copy = ROOT.DS.'tmpupload'.DS.$this->Auth->user('person_id').DS.$name_image_2.'.'.$ext;
            //por ultimo mi función que procesa la imagen
            $img->compresed($path, $path_copy, 25);
            echo json_encode($imgtmp['name']);
            die();
        }
    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

el problema esta que no veo que el archivo se cree lo intente sobre escribiendo la misma imagen pero verifique el peso en megas y pesa igual que cuando se subió la imagen

Comment: te votaron negativo porque tienes el codigo en un imagen

Comment: Gracias ya lo modifique

Comment: ¿Dónde guardas la imagen comprimida?

Comment: aqui alvaro $path_copy = ROOT.DS.'tmpupload'.DS.$this->Auth->user('person_id').DS.$name_image_2.'.'.$ext;

Comment: @JonathanCunza Hay sólo estás indicando la ruta donde se debe guardar. Pero, ¿dónde guardas la imagen comprimida?

Comment: mmm entonces no estoy enviado el nuevo archivo

Comment: No, y ese es el problema. Deja y te pongo una respuesta con más detalles.

Comment: Ok alavaro espero tu respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Comunidad aquí les coloco mi solución con la librería de imagemagick

```
  //Funcion que comprime y corta la imagen sin perder su calidad
  public function compresed($path,$file,$ext,$quality) {

    $this->rotate($file);
    $img = new \Imagick($file);
    $img->setcompressionquality($quality);
    $img->resizeimage(400, 600,  \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1,TRUE);
    $img->setFormat("jpg");
    $img_name = $this->uniquename();
    $img->writeimages($path.DS.$img_name.'.'.$ext,true);
    return $img_name.'.'.$ext;
}
 //Función para rotar la imagen en caso sea subida desde un celular
public function rotate($file) {

    $exif = exif_read_data($file);
    $img = new \Imagick($file);
    if(isset($exif['Orientation']) && $exif['Orientation'] == '6'){
        $img->rotateimage('black', $this->setting['degrees']);
    }
    if(isset($exif['Orientation']) && $exif['Orientation'] == '3'){
        $img->rotateimage('black', $this->setting['degrees']);
    }

    return $file;
}
```

espero que le sirva a alguien que lo necesite gracias al resto por sus repuesta :)

Comment: Tu respuesta no esta completa?

Comment: a que te retefieres con no estar completa bueno esas es la función o que le faltaría para que este mejor

Comment: me puedes pasar los datos de imagemagick por que no lo e podido descargar

Comment: mmm a que te refieres la instalación de la extensión

Comment: si amigo eso es lo que te falta en el codigo

Comment: pero la instalación de la extensión imagick lo seguí de un vídeo en youtube y luego solo use la clase nada mas quieres el enlace del video ya que alli te data toda la información de donde descargar los paquetes y demas

Comment: bien amigo gracias lo intentare usando composer

Comment: mira aquí te dejo en enlace la instalación es para windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh0YJl1dUs8 no se si pueda instalar desde composer ya que la instalación abarca configuración dentro de apache

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo te recomiendo usar [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de su uso si lo que buscas es quitarle el peso a las imágenes.

Esta funcion toma un nombre de archivo de imagen, luego carga,

lo convierte y lo guarda como un nuevo archivo. 
Los argumentos.

Los requerido son:

$fromfile: Ruta y / o nombre de la imagen a convertir

$tofile: ruta y / o nombre de la imagen a convertir

$type: Tipo de archivo para convertir:

"gif": Convertir a una imagen gif

"jpeg": convierte a una imagen jpeg

"png": Convertir a una imagen png

$calidad: Calidad de imagen (0-99).

Sólo usado si el $type es jpeg o png

0 = calidad más baja y tamaño más pequeño

99 = La mejor calidad y el tamaño más grande

```
PIPHP_ImageConvert("photo.jpg", "photo4.png", "png", 0);

function PIPHP_ImageConvert($fromfile, $tofile, $type, $quality)
{
   $contents = file_get_contents($fromfile);
   $image    = imagecreatefromstring($contents);

   switch($type)
   {
      case "gif":  imagegif($image,  $tofile); break;
      case "jpeg": imagejpeg($image, $tofile, $quality); break;
      case "png":  imagepng($image,  $tofile,
                     round(9 - $quality * .09)); break;
   }
}





<?

$origen="img/imagen.jpg";

$destino="img/nuevaimagen.jpg";

$destino_temporal=tempnam("tmp/","tmp");

redimensionar_jpeg($origen, $destino_temporal, 300, 350, 100);



// guardamos la imagen

$fp=fopen($destino,"w");

fputs($fp,fread(fopen($destino_temporal,"r"),filesize($destino_temporal)));

fclose($fp);



// mostramos la imagen

echo "<img src='img/nuevaimagen.jpg'>";



function redimensionar_jpeg($img_original, $img_nueva, $img_nueva_anchura, $img_nueva_altura, $img_nueva_calidad)

{

    // crear una imagen desde el original 

    $img = ImageCreateFromJPEG($img_original);

    // crear una imagen nueva 

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($img_nueva_anchura,$img_nueva_altura);

    // redimensiona la imagen original copiandola en la imagen 

    ImageCopyResized($thumb,$img,0,0,0,0,$img_nueva_anchura,$img_nueva_altura,ImageSX($img),ImageSY($img));

    // guardar la nueva imagen redimensionada donde indicia $img_nueva 

    ImageJPEG($thumb,$img_nueva,$img_nueva_calidad);

    ImageDestroy($img);

}

?>
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta algo similar use antes pero comprobe el peso de cada archivo y no hacia mucha diferencia por eso estoy probando con imagemagick cabe mencionar que estaba usando otra funcion imagecreatefromjpeg distinta a la que mencionas tu habria que probar y ver que tanta diferencia hace

Comment: Usando esta forma logro convertir por ejemplo una imagen de 42Kb jpeg a una de 8kb sin problemas

Comment: por ejemplo si fuese una imagen de 3mb que es una imagen de una foto tomada desde el celular hasta cuanto lo podría bajar su peso si tardarse mucho

Comment: Creo que deberías de re dimensionar la imagen

Comment: Revisa el código que actualice

Comment: claro eso siempre el usuario tendría la opción del el mismo cambiarle el tamaño a la imagen en este caso solo se desea subir la imagen y que la aplicación haga el trabajo no se si me dejo entender o yo no te estoy entendiendo